# Find Up-Vector for LookAt Matrix (2 rotations)

Tags: graphics, 3d, transform

I'm trying to establish a lookAt matrix to look at the point {0,0,0} from an eye at {5,5,10}. I've successfully implemented the LookAt matrix for an eye at {5,0,10}, but the second angle (y direction) throws off my 'up' vector so it isn't {0,1,0} anymore. Can someone help me determine what my 'up' vector should be in terms of my eye matrix? I'd like to keep the x axis parallel with the horizon.

I'm using Mathematica, but am going to implement in Python...

Below is the code for using an eye at {5,0,10}, but I'd like to change the eye to {5,5,10}, and figure out the correct 'up' vector

```js
   `eye = {5, 5, 10};
   l = {0, 0, 0};
   Mt = IdentityMatrix[4];
   F = l - eye;
   Mt[[1 ;; 3, 4]] = -eye;

   >>>Mt={{1, 0, 0, -5}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, -10}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}

   forward = Normalize[F];
   up = Normalize[{0, 1, 0}];
   left = Cross[up, forward];
   Mr = IdentityMatrix[4];
   Mr[[1, 1 ;; 3]] = left;
   Mr[[2, 1 ;; 3]] = up;
   Mr[[3, 1 ;; 3]] = forward;
   >>> Mr={{-0.894427, 0., 0.447214, 0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0.}, {-0.447214, 
  0., -0.894427, 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}

   >>>Mr.Mt={{-0.894427, 0., 0.447214, 0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0.},    {-0.447214, 
  0., -0.894427, 11.1803}, {0., 0., 0., 1.}}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-orthogonalize your up-vector:

```
up = Cross[forward, left];
```